# Tricky rss to read with curl

Tags: php, curl, rss, rss-reader

Does any body know hot to make this feed http://maxhire.net/cp/?EA5E6F361D4364703D044F72 to be read with curl?
i clearly miss some curl conf, but i'm new to this, usually do JS

```
function url_get_contents ($Url) {

if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
    die('CURL is not installed!');
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
}
```

And calling the script as below,

```
echo url_get_contents('http://maxhire.net/cp/?EA5E6F361D4364703D044F72');
```

does not work for THIS FEED and works with any other, say http: / / x ml.corriereobjects.it/rss/homepage.xml

Comment: technically you only need `file_get_contents('http://....')`, assuming PHP's `allow_url_fopen` is enabled. Most likely that feed is doing UA and/or referer filtering, so you'll have to do a better job of pretending to be a regular browser.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment
file_get_contents was the first option but even with allow_url_fopen set true did not work for THIS url :-(
Your hint of "pretenting to be a regular browser" gave me few ideas like user agent... but of course if anyone knows the solution is more than welcome !! I'm a client side guy ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This website seems to expect a cookie named `AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport`, if it didn't find it it will redirect you to some cookie detection page, and it will stuck in a loop:

```
> curl -I -L http://maxhire.net/cp/?EA5E6F361D4364703D044F72
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2013 23:10:55 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Location: /cp/?EA5E6F361D4364703D044F72&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 180
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1; path=/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2013 23:10:56 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Location: /cp/?EA5E6F361D4364703D044F72&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 214
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1; path=/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2013 23:10:57 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Location: /cp/?EA5E6F361D4364703D044F72&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 248
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1; path=/


^C
```

So you need to set this cookie: `AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1');
```

That solved the first problem, another problem came up, if you didn't set a value for the user-agent it will send you this page:

```
<html xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1" /><
title>
        Untitled Page
</title><link href="App_Themes/Default/Common.css" type="text/css" rel="styleshe
et" /><link href="App_Themes/Default/Container.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesh
eet" /><link href="App_Themes/Default/Content.css" type="text/css" rel="styleshe
et" /><link href="App_Themes/Default/Login.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
 /></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="rssCurrentJobs.aspx?site=5E6F361D43
64703D044F72" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTc2MTg4
NDc4NmRk" />

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So add a user-agent value:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "SomeUserAgent");
```

Full code:

```
function url_get_contents ($Url) {

    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "SomeUserAgent");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1');
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Sir!
Let me know if i can help back with anything :-)